# Ubicacion mapsforge

Tags: android, mapsforge

Estoy intentando obtener la ubicación con mapsforge 0.6.1, pero en el método `onCreate()` al asignar latitud y longitud me aparece este error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.example.luis.safe, PID: 27378
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.luis.safe.Tracker: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2905)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1439)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at com.example.luis.safe.Tracker.onCreate(Tracker.java:57)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2895)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1439) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)

Este es mi código

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


import org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong;
import org.mapsforge.map.model.MapViewPosition;
import org.mapsforge.core.model.Point;
import org.mapsforge.core.model.BoundingBox;

public class Tracker extends Service implements LocationListener{
public Tracker() {
}

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

private static final String TAG = Tracker.class.getSimpleName();

Location location;
double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;

private LatLong latLong;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 5 * 1; // 5 segundos, 1000 * 60 * 1 ---> 1 minuto

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    latitude = latLong.getLatitude();
    longitude = latLong.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //myTask.execute();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    System.out.println(latitude + "" + longitude);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable `latLong` es nula dentro de tu `onCreate()`, debes asegurar tenga un valor diferente a null, la estas definiendo:

```
private LatLong latLong;
```

pero no le asignas valor, por eso marca error en esta linea de código al llamar el método `getLatitude()` sobre la instancia `latLong` de valor null:

```
  latitude = latLong.getLatitude();
  longitude = latLong.getLongitude();
```